# Wait for user input?

Tags: java, android, user-input

I am trying to redesign a text based terminal rpg I wrote in Java, as an Android app. I'm working on a small piece of the game, where the player can walk from one room to another.

Where the code would stop and prompt the user for input in the terminal app, now it simply runs all the way through to the end and won't take any input.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//rooms
Room r1 = new Room("The Great Hall", "A long wide room draped here and there in curtains.");
Room r2 = new Room("The Side Study", "a small cluttered room.");
Room r3 = new Room("The Gardens", "a misty path between beds, once carefully tended now overgrown and disturbed by the encroaching weeds.");
Room r4 = new Room("A Long Passage", "a narrow hallway lined with brooding portraits. Set into the walls to your left and right are blank grey doors, three to a side. They are locked.");
Room currentRoom;

//room maps
HashMap<String, Room> mapR1 = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, Room> mapR2 = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, Room> mapR3 = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, Room> mapR4 = new HashMap<>();

//user
String userDir;
String endgame;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //begin setup
    //

    //map for great hall
    mapR1.put("north", r4);
    mapR1.put("east", r2);
    mapR1.put("west", r3);
    r1.setRoomMap(mapR1);

    //map for side study
    mapR2.put("west", r1);
    r2.setRoomMap(mapR2);

    //map for gardens
    mapR3.put("east", r1);
    r3.setRoomMap(mapR3);

    //map for long passage
    mapR4.put("south", r1);
    r4.setRoomMap(mapR4);

    //init
    currentRoom = r1;
    endgame = "non";

    //views
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.youmum);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    //
    //end setup

    //the actual game play
    //

    assert textView != null;
    textView.setText("You are in the " + currentRoom.getRoomTitle() + "; " + currentRoom.getRoomDescription());
    textView.append("\nThere are exits to the, ");

    for (String ky : currentRoom.getRoomMap().keySet()) {
        textView.append(ky + " ");
    }

    textView.append("\nChoose a direction");

    assert editText != null;
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
                sendMessage();
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }

        private void sendMessage() {
            userDir = editText.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
            if (userDir.contains("go") || userDir.contains("walk") || userDir.contains("move")) {
                boolean notDir = false;
                for (String kee : currentRoom.getRoomMap().keySet()) {
                    if (userDir.contains(kee)) {
                        currentRoom = currentRoom.getExitRoom(kee);
                        notDir = false;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        notDir = true;
                    }
                }
                if (notDir) {
                    textView.setText("You cannot go that way.\n");
                }
            }
        }

    });

    textView.setText("You are in the " + currentRoom.getRoomTitle() + "; " + currentRoom.getRoomDescription());
    textView.append("\nThere are exits to the, ");

    for (String ky : currentRoom.getRoomMap().keySet()) {
        textView.append(ky + " ");
    }

    textView.append("\nChoose a direction");

  }
 }
```

I am very new to Android (this is actually my first foray) so I'm assuming I am just missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code at the bottom (which displays text about the new room you have moved into) needs to be moved inside the ActionListener, so that it runs each time the event triggers and not just once as everything is being initialised. You could put it in sendMessage() after the existing code which updates currentRoom.

You may have done this already, but in order for the IME_ACTION_SEND event to be triggered, the XML defining the EditText should include:

```
android:imeOptions="actionSend"
```

You may also want to add some code to clear the EditText content, as that will stay there currently after the user hits "send".